# How do I rename a default AWS RDS option group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, terraform

I'm trying to bring our AWS account under terraform but it's throwing an error the that RDS Option group name isn't supported it has a colon in it. How do I rename it either via the GUI or CLI so it can then be managed by terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the AWS side:

1. You cannot modify the default RDS option group.  However, you can create a new one and give it the name of your choice, after which you can associate it with your RDS instance.
2. The name of the option group "can contain only letters, digits, and hyphens."  So that error message about a colon in the name is misleading.

Reference:  [Working with option groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithOptionGroups.html)

Comment: Just to add - I removed the configuration for the default ones so it's not managed by terraform and instead created new options groups that are.